# Chained selection of Credit Card database schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

I am not very good in database design so please if you can help me with this. I want to know what will be the best way to store it in mysql database

Here is the selection I want as final

1. **Select Card Issuer** this will be list of banks issuer
2. **Card Type**  it will be Prepaid, Credit or Debit

Below Card Categories will be fetched according to above 2 selection

3. **Card Categories**
4. **Affiliation** VISA, MASTER etc.

I have come-up with below schema of 5 `tables`

```
issuer
  id   |  int
  name |  varchar

card_type
  id   |  int
  name |  varchar

card_categories
  id            |  int
  name          |  varchar
  issuer_id     |  int     ref to issuer
  card_type_id  |  int     ref to card_type

card_affiliation
  id   |  int
  name |  varchar 

cards
  id                   |  int
  name                 |  varchar
  card_categories_id   |  int         ref to card_categories
  card_affiliation_id  |  int         ref to card_affiliation
```

**End Goal:**

User just select the card issuer and choose a type. then he/she will be presented with the list of categories for selected issuer by card type.

> Please note this system is for display the cards in selected `issuer`
>   and `card_type`, I am not asking for **card number** or any other
>   thing.

Comment: Something to note: you can infer a lot of your information from the card number itself.  If the card starts with `4` it's a Visa, if it starts with `3` it's an AMEX, and on.  See: https://creditcardjs.com/credit-card-type-detection Also, the first 6 digits are the BIN number, and can tell you the issuer. There are databases you can subscribe to for fetching this: http://www.binlist.net/

Comment: Thanks @PaulProgrammer, for the info, it will be good for other project, but in this case i am not storing/asking any card number for the safer side. I am just interested in card provided by different issuer with there categories etc

Comment: saving the first 6 digits is perfectly safe and sanctioned under PCI.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to ask for card number, since we are not accepting any payment, what about above database schema, it will work or do i need to move something, thanks for info anyway

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't because it allows you to answer the questions you posed.  Your schema is officially StackOverflow Community Approved(tm) by folks who know nothing about your project.